# Installing Oracle 11g in virtualbox

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, virtualbox

I am a newbie to virtualbox and oracle. My task is to do some kind of research on .vmdk files in virtual box. I have windows 7 in host and as well as in virtual machine(guest). In the virtual machine I have a .vmdk(c: drive) file where the windows OS runs. I have additionally added another .vdmk file (another additional hard drive D:) .

My question is, will it be possible to install oracle in C:\ drive and have the database store(all the tables and data in database ) in other .vdmk file i.e D:\Drive. So that it will be easy to give the second vmdk file(D:) to other person who already has virtual machine setup with windows and Oracle installed in it instead of giving the person the whole .vmdk setup (consists of windows setup,C:). Is it possible to split oracle installation file and datastore folders into other disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely, the DBCA during installation will allow you specify the ORACLE_HOME (binaries, etc C:) and your oradata (DBF files, D:) wherever you would like.